# How to call setListAdapter for ListView contained in a Fragment

Tags: java, android

All the examples I see of `ListView`'s tend to be either implementations of `ListActivity` or `ListFragment`, where `setListAdapter()` is called in the `onCreate()` event.

However, I want to have a `ListView` contained within another `Fragment`, I don't want to have the `ListView` as the `Fragment` itself...if you know what I mean.

I want to know if I have xml for my `Fragment` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    >

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_menu" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

How do you call `setListAdapter` for the list view in the fragment class? I have seen an example where a `ListView` is contained in an `Activity` and you call `findViewById()` to get the `ListView` object and then call `setListAdapter()`.

However, the `Fragment` class doesn't have the `findViewById` method so how do you get a reference to the `ListView` object?

Answer (score 2):

Just a disclaimer, I haven't really tried it myself, but reading from the API Doc, you might be able to call [getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView%28%29) to get the root view of your Fragment.
Presumably you are going to instantiate the XML Layour via [onCreateView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView%28android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle%29)

Once you get the root view, I think you might be able to access the ListView via the usual `findViewById`

Comment: well done sir - your exactly right, getView is precisely what I need!

Comment: Can you please explain in a sample code, how to do it exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, the fragment can access the Activity instance with getActivity() and easily perform tasks such as find a view in the activity layout:

```
View listView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this comes late but I thought I'll answer in case it helps anyone else. You can have a ListView inside a normal fragment just like you would any other widget. And you can also have several other widgets within that same fragment. In this case you inflate the Fragment using onCreateView as follows:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // I gave the default list id
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter); // your customAdapter should have already been initialzed at this point
    // Initialize other items  - Buttons, EditTexts... etc.
}
```

Then you just treat it as you would with any ListAdapter object